# binding height/width to child element in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

Let me start by saying sorry if this is a duplicate.  I was unable to find an answer in any of the similar posts that I have read.  I am having an issue where I have a `Border` control whose `Height` and `Width` are bound to the `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` of a `TextBlock` that is a child of the `Border`.

Everything displays fine in the designer, but for some reason at run-time, the `Border` control is not visible.  I am not sure if it is because the `Height` or `Width` may be `0`, or perhaps the `Visibility` is being set some other way.  If I hard code the `Height`/`Width` then everything displays the same in the designer and at runtime, but something is acting bizarre with this binding.  Even more bizarre, is that they were working before, and I'm not sure what I could have done to break them.  Here is my XAML:

```
<Grid Visibility="{Binding Path=Contacts.Count, Converter={StaticResource ItemCountToVisibilityConverter}}" >
    <Border CornerRadius="5"
            BorderBrush="White"
            BorderThickness="2"
            Padding="20,15,0,15"
            Margin="0,15,0,15">
         <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Contacts}">
             <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                     <StackPanel>
                         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Number}" />
                         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=EmailAddress}" />
                     </StackPanel>
                 </DataTemplate>
             </ListView.ItemTemplate>
         </ListView>
     </Border>
     <Border Background="White"
             CornerRadius="5"
             Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=ContactsTextBlock}"
             Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=ContactsTextBlock}"
             VerticalAlignment="Top">
          <TextBlock Text="Contact Information"  
                     x:Name="ContactsTextBlock"
                     Foreground="Black"
                     Padding="5,2,5,2"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

It is the second `Border` control in the XAML that is having the issue.  As I said, it displays properly in the designer, but for some reason at runtime, the `Border` control as well as the `TextBlock` it contains are not visible.  Also, the `Grid` is working properly, as well as the `ListView` and the first `Border`.  It is simply the second `Border` and it's `TextBlock` that are not functioning properly.

Thanks in advance!

Here is what it looks like at design-time:

[image: contact info image]

Comment: The very first question is: why are you setting the size of the border? The same question could be: what are trying to do? Aside your own problem, you should *never* bind (i.e. rely) on children element, because (1) they are instantiated AFTER the parent, and (2) the fundamental yet awesome goal of WPF/XAML is templating, which allows to decouple very well fragments of visual tree.

Comment: I am basically trying to create a similar experience to a GroupBox.  I will add a picture of what it looks like at design time to show what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @MarioVernari I will just hard code the values for now.  Do you have any suggestions that may allow for similar behavior?  Thanks,

Comment: Also, the only reason for the Border control is that I cannot set the background color of a TextBlock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the Grid do the dirty work for you. I believe the Grid is one of the best controls WPF has.

The trick is dividing the vertical space in three slices, where the two on the top are sized accordingly to the desired space. That is, the TextBlock will determine how tall will be the row pair. You don't have to do anything than enjoying the result...

Here is a sample XAML (I cut the Visibility property for sake of simplicity):

```
<Grid Margin="40,20">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border 
        CornerRadius="5"
        BorderBrush="White"
        BorderThickness="2"
        Padding="20,15,20,15"
        Background="DimGray"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        >
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Contacts}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Number}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=EmailAddress}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Border>

    <Border 
        Background="White"
        CornerRadius="5"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        >
        <TextBlock 
            Text="Contact Information"  
            x:Name="ContactsTextBlock"
            Foreground="Black"
            Padding="5,2,5,2"
            />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Please, note the ListView border is sharing the middle row, so that the borderline will run "striking" the text.

That renders as follows:

[image]

Comment: This is much nicer than what I had.  That works splendid!  Thanks.  I will try to avoid binding to child elements in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to set up `BorderThickness` and `BorderBrush`:

```
 <Border Background="White"
     Border Background="White"
     CornerRadius="5"
     BorderThickness="1"
     BorderBrush="Gray"
     HorizontalAlignment="Center"
     VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <TextBlock Text="Contact Information"  
             x:Name="ContactsTextBlock"
             Foreground="Black"
             Padding="5,2,5,2"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
             VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Border>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not make a difference.  As I mentioned in the post, the `Border` displays properly at runtime if I hard code the `Width` and `Height`.  I am hoping to avoid that though, as perhaps the font could change in the future, or some other factor such as different text or something could change the needed size.  Thanks anyway though.

Comment: @dubstylee I run the code you proveded and border was visible when BorderThickness and BorderBrush was set (since they have "no default value" as MSDN says). If this is not it, then there must be something else at play here, that is outside of the code you provided. Are you styling your controls somwhere? (Also, you may want to do HorizontalAlignment="Center" on your border instead of binding to child's width)